# Add column name to a variable and use it in later calculation in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem. I need to determine the name of the column under which the calculations will continue. So I wrote a select:

```
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnA VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnB VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ColumnA = 'RegistrationDate'
SET @ColumnB = 'EntryDate'
SET @column = CASE
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) NOT IN (
        '2021-08-04','2021-08-05','2021-08-06','2021-08-07','2021-08-08','2021-08-09','2021-08-10','2021-09-07','2021-09-08','2021-09-09','2021-09-10','2021-09-11',
'2021-09-12','2021-09-13','2021-10-05','2021-10-06','2021-10-07','2021-10-08','2021-10-09','2021-10-10','2021-10-11','2021-11-09','2021-11-10','2021-11-11','2021-11-12','2021-11-13','2021-11-14','2021-11-15','2021-12-07',
'2021-12-08','2021-12-09','2021-12-10','2021-12-11','2021-12-12','2021-12-13'
        ) THEN
            QUOTENAME(@Column)
        ELSE
            QUOTENAME(@ColumnB)
    END

SELECT @column
```

which returns me `[RegistrationDate]` or `[EntryDate]` and stores this in variable `@column`. Now, when I know under which column should I calculate, I want to insert this variable `@column` in to my main select one of the `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnA VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnB VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ColumnA = 'RegistrationDate'
SET @ColumnB = 'EntryDate'
SET @column = CASE
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) NOT IN (
        '2021-08-04','2021-08-05','2021-08-06','2021-08-07','2021-08-08','2021-08-09','2021-08-10','2021-09-07','2021-09-08','2021-09-09','2021-09-10','2021-09-11',
'2021-09-12','2021-09-13','2021-10-05','2021-10-06','2021-10-07','2021-10-08','2021-10-09','2021-10-10','2021-10-11','2021-11-09','2021-11-10','2021-11-11','2021-11-12','2021-11-13','2021-11-14','2021-11-15','2021-12-07',
'2021-12-08','2021-12-09','2021-12-10','2021-12-11','2021-12-12','2021-12-13'
        ) THEN
            QUOTENAME(@Column)
        ELSE
            QUOTENAME(@ColumnB)
    END

SELECT
    CASE WHEN final.Branch IS NULL THEN 'Total'
         ELSE final.Branch
    END AS 'Branch',
    final.TR

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CASE 
                WHEN main.BRANCHNO = 1 THEN 'One'
                WHEN main.BRANCHNO = 2 THEN 'Two'
                WHEN main.BRANCHNO = 3 THEN 'Three'
                WHEN main.BRANCHNO = 4 THEN 'Four'
                WHEN main.BRANCHNO = 5 THEN 'Five'
                WHEN main.BRANCHNO = 6 THEN 'Six'
            END AS 'Branch',
            COUNT(*) AS 'TR'

        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                [TABLE]
            WHERE
                Status = 100
                AND
                BRANCHNO IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
                AND
                Type = 'TR'
                AND
                **@column** = CONVERT(DATE, CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, getdate()) = 'Monday' THEN getdate()-3 ELSE getdate()-1 END
        )
    ) AS main
GROUP BY
    main.BRANCHNO WITH ROLLUP
) AS final
```

But when I execute query it returns me an error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 Conversion failed when converting
> date and/or time from character string.

I imagined everything very simple: I put a column name into a variable, and then, that name placed at the beginning of the `WHERE` clause will be recognized as the column name and then `*= CONVERT(DATE, CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, getdate()) etc` will do all work.

But that did not happen. Maybe someone knows why and maybe they know how to solve this task?

Comment: SQL Server does not let you use variables to specify database object identifiers (table names, column names, etc), so you need to use Dynamic SQL (i.e. string-building with `sp_executesql`) which is fraught with danger. Have fun.

Comment: That said, if you're only checking one of 2 columns (`RegistrationDate` and `EntryDate`) then there are simpler (and better) alternatives.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `SELECT *` in a nested-query when the outer-query is only using a single column (`branchno`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable to reference a column name.  `@column` is just a piece of data, which just so happens to contain a column name as a string, but it's still just a string, not actually a reference to a column in a table.

Some options you have seem to be...

```
AND CASE @column WHEN 'RegistrationDate' THEN RegistrationDate
                 WHEN 'EntryDate'        THEN EntryDate
    END
    =
    CONVERT(DATE, CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, getdate()) = 'Monday' THEN getdate()-3 ELSE getdate()-1 END)
```

Or, have two queries which only differ in the column being referenced...

```
IF (@column = 'RegistrationDate')
  <query1>
ELSE IF (@column = 'EntryDate')
  <query2>
```

Or "Dynamic SQL" where you build up a new string with your SQL code and execute that by call `sp_executesql` *(assuming this is SQL Server, which it appears to be)*.

I recommend reading this : https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

***EDIT:*** A pure SQL alternative, assuming SQL Server

```
DECLARE @mode INT = CASE
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) NOT IN (
        '2021-08-04','2021-08-05','2021-08-06','2021-08-07','2021-08-08','2021-08-09','2021-08-10','2021-09-07','2021-09-08','2021-09-09','2021-09-10','2021-09-11',
'2021-09-12','2021-09-13','2021-10-05','2021-10-06','2021-10-07','2021-10-08','2021-10-09','2021-10-10','2021-10-11','2021-11-09','2021-11-10','2021-11-11','2021-11-12','2021-11-13','2021-11-14','2021-11-15','2021-12-07',
'2021-12-08','2021-12-09','2021-12-10','2021-12-11','2021-12-12','2021-12-13'
        ) THEN
            0
        ELSE
            1
    END;

DECLARE @filter_date DATE = CONVERT(DATE, CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, getdate()) = 'Monday' THEN getdate()-3 ELSE getdate()-1 END;

WITH
  source AS
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    [TABLE]
  WHERE
        Status = 100
    AND BRANCHNO IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
    AND Type = 'TR'
),
  filtered_source AS
(
  SELECT 0 AS mode, * FROM source WHERE RegistrationDate = @filter_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS mode, * FROM source WHERE EntryDate        = @filter_date
)
SELECT
  COALESCE(
    CASE 
      WHEN BRANCHNO = 1 THEN 'One'
      WHEN BRANCHNO = 2 THEN 'Two'
      WHEN BRANCHNO = 3 THEN 'Three'
      WHEN BRANCHNO = 4 THEN 'Four'
      WHEN BRANCHNO = 5 THEN 'Five'
      WHEN BRANCHNO = 6 THEN 'Six'
    END,
    'Total'
  )
    AS 'Branch',
  COUNT(*) AS 'TR'
FROM
  filtered_source
WHERE
  mode = @mode
GROUP BY
  GROUPING SETS (
    (mode),
    (mode, BRANCHNO)
  );
```

By always including `mode` in the `GROUPING SETS`, the optimiser ***might*** be able to yield a better execution plan for the two scenarios.

Still read the link given above though, at the very least to understand why this is necessary, or perhaps why it doesn't quite manage to yield the best execution plan.

Comment: It's amazing that SQL has been around for a half-century now, and we've had our _best practices_ for working with SQL for decades, and yet there is still no good way to dynamically build a query in SQL, so we're forced to use terribly unsafe practices like Dynamic SQL or third-party external ORMs like EF. It's crazy how we've gotten this far and _still no-one_ in the Oracle, Postgres and SQL Server teams decided "maybe we should fix this"...

Comment: @Dai - I partly agree with you.  I say partly because in 90% of the cases I see, the need for Dynamic SQL can be removed with normalised structures.  In trivial terms, if you treat a table as a spreadsheet, it will come up repeatedly, but much less so if you use normalised models.  The extreme consequence of that though is everything becomes EAV tables, and that's bad too.  So, why don't vendors extend SQL to accommodate that 10% of cases? Again trivially put, it will have a massive cascade effect on the optimisers/planners and will be an expensive exercise, without sufficient commercial gain.